# Finding the electric potential inside a dielectric

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, dielectric

So this is more of a conceptual question. When trying to find the electric potential inside a dielectric, we often use the fact that we know the form of solutions to Laplace's equation $ \nabla^2 \Phi = 0$ and then use boundary conditions to find the coefficients. However, we know that, in the presence of an external field $\vec{E}_0$, inside the dielectric the free charge density $\rho_{free} = 0$ but $\rho \neq 0$. Also knowing that for the electric displacement we have $\nabla \cdot \vec{D} = \rho_{free}$, this would lead me to think that the potential we have found actually describes $\vec{D}$ not the electric field inside  $\vec{E}_{IN}$.

However, whenever I look at examples from our course, after finding the potential inside a dielectric, the electric field is just found through $\vec{E} = -\nabla \Phi$ which doesn't make sense to me. What is going on here?